# elliptic curve with Teichmüller parameter $τ=i$

Tags: complex-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let the complex form $z_{1}+dz_{1}\wedge dz_{2}$ on $D^{2}\times T^{2}$ ,where $D^2$ is a unit disk un $z_{1}$-plane. here $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ is a standard coordinates on $\mathbb{C^2}$. I read on paper that on $z_{1}=0$ the complex structure is smooth elliptic curve with Teichmüller parameter $τ=i$.

Can you simple description to “smooth elliptic curve with Teichmüller parameter $τ=i$”?

I have introduction knowledge about complex geometry ie, if you describe it with standard complex coordinates, with standard 1-form or integrable complex structure , I understand very easily.

Comment: Up to a constant there is only one holomorphic one-form on a complex elliptic curve, integrating it yields an isomorphism to $\Bbb{C/(u_1Z+u_2Z)}$ where $u_j = \int_{\gamma_j} \omega$ and $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ generate the homology group, on the other hand, once your know $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$, to each $u_1,u_2$ there is a complex structure $S(u_1,u_2)$, and $S(u_1,u_2)$ is biholomorphic to $S(au_1+bu_2,cu_1+du_2),a,b,c,d\in \Bbb{Z}, ad-bc=1$. Here you have $(u_1,u_2) = (1,i)$.

Comment: It is not clear what does $z_1 + dz_1 \wedge dz_2$ mean. How to add a local function to a 2-form?

Comment: @reuns first thank you very much for your answer, so two question:1. Why elliptic curve has only holomorphic bundle? 2. You say we have a space, where it is all elliptic curves up to biholomorphic, and this elliptic curve is $τ=i$ with SL(2,\mathbb{R}) natural action?

Comment: @ArcticChar sorry I forgot to say $(z_{1},z_{2})$ is standard coordinates, i fix it now

Comment: @reuns You are master and perfect on elliptic curves and complex geometry . Can you introduce to me what is best reference on elliptic curve and complex geometry?

Comment: @ArcticChar it is generator of a line bundle.